# Regex pattern does not tidy up YouTube URLs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace all parts before youtube.com in a URL with nothing, but my regex expression seems to do nothing.

For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8 -> youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8 -> youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8
www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8 -> youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8
```

```js
function setYoutubeUrl(youtubeUrl: string) {
    return youtubeUrl.replace(
      /((\/+|https??:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?=youtube\.com\/.+\/.)|(?<=youtube\.com\/.+\/.)\/*([?#].*)?)/gi,
      ''
    );
}

console.log(setYoutubeUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5iJV2cYCt8"));
```

Comment: Consider using [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and grab the appropriate properties. The only thing you should need to remove is "www." that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the regex `/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i`. So your function will be like this:

```
function setYoutubeUrl(youtubeUrl) {
    return youtubeUrl.replace(
      /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?/i,
      ''
    );
}
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `^` asserts position at start of the string
- **Non-capturing group** `(?:https:\/\/)?`

  - `?` matches the previous token between `zero` and `one` times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `http` matches the characters `http` literally (case insensitive)

    - `s` matches the character s literally (case insensitive)
    - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `:` matches the character `:` literally (case insensitive)
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case insensitive)
  - `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case insensitive)
- **Non-capturing group** `(?:www\.)?`

  - `?` matches the previous token between `zero` and `one` times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `www` matches the characters `www` literally (case insensitive)
  - `\.` matches the character `.` literally (case insensitive)
- **Global pattern flags**

  - `i` modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of `[a-zA-Z]`)